# Thread-first, thread-last and "dot" form

Tags: clojure, macros, clojure-java-interop

Why do both of these expressions give the same result?

`> (macroexpand-all '(->> "string" (.charAt)))`

`(. "string" charAt)`

`> (macroexpand-all '(-> "string" (.charAt)))`

`(. "string" charAt)`

Isn't "->>" macro supposed to insert "string" as the last element in the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It expands first to `(.charAt "string")`, which indeed is last. Then that form further expands to `(. "string" charAt)`.